# Intermittent "There was no endpoint listening at" error

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, networking, enterprise

We are having a fairly rare issue with our enterprise system where this issue gets thrown:

> Error Message: There was no endpoint listening at dataserviceurl.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> Stack Trace: Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at Project.DataServices.IGetData.GetAllUserTask(String productTypeID, String userID, String taskType, String fullName) at Project.PresentationLayer.Pages.TaskMessenger.GetGroupTask() at Project.PresentationLayer.Pages.TaskMessenger.b__1() at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

A few people in the business have had this issue. One person more than others. And they are in different locations. We've had server updates, changes in computer hardware and various other "networking" changes but the issues hasn't be resolved.

It has also be noted that the error comes up most often whenever a particular user locks the computer and comes back to it later.

Most of the data I could get from this issue is when dealing with the problem when it has put the system in lockdown and nothing works but this happens, like I said, pretty infrequently.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT 1:**
As a side note, we haven't been able to recreate the issue within either the IT or Development team so we cannot pin down the inner exception. Also, I should note that we open a connection per request as opposed to keeping the connection open.

**EDIT 2:**
We are running on .Net 4.0 also. Just more context

Comment: Is the client and connection "always on" or is it established for each request?

Comment: It is established for each request

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this one?